# Change element attributes by scroll location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to reduce the `top` property on an element as a user scrolls down my web page, so that the top equals `0` when the user is around `250px` down the web page. Currently, I have to work with this css:

```
[data-label="label1"] {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 89px;
 }
```

When the browser reaches `250px` I want the `top` to equal `0px`. How can I write this with jQuery?

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scrollTop()` property of the `window` when it's scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('[data-label="label1"]').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() > 250 ? 0 : '89px');
});
```

Comment: Ok great thanks. Having difficulty using `animate` in this framework, however. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start another question about that, as it doesn't seem related to this question.